# After the installation open a blank solve SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have been working on this problem for a week now and finally found the solution, so I thought I'd share it since I could not find it on google.

I was getting the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Tracker :: get_recently_viewed () [ tracker.get-recently-viewed ]: The script trie d to execute a method or access a property of an
>   incomplete object Please ensur e that the class definition & quot;.
>   BreadCrumbStack & quot; of the object you are tr ying to operate on
>   was loaded *before* unserialize () gets called or provide a __
>   autoload () function to load the class definition in / usr / www /
>   virtual / wiredops / w
>   ww.dance-studio-websites.com/crm/include/utils/mvc_utils.php(49): eval
>   () 'd code on line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being 2 things:

1. The session directory being set in apache / php was not correct, which had to be changed in php.ini with the variable session.save_path
2. The session.auto_start in php.ini needed to be set to OFF

Modify the value in php.ini

session.auto_start = 0

Then after the restart apache OK it!